# Could not load type 'Owin.Extensions' from assembly 'Nancy.Owin, Version=0.23.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, owin, nancy

I did a big round of NuGet updates for my .NET 4.5 Nancy/Owin app.  Now I'm getting the above error message and I'm stumped.

I definitely have a reference to Owin.Extensions present, and it's there in the executable directory as well.

I have a parallel set of projects doing this under MONO and it continues to operate smoothly, even after the NuGet updates.

Thought: I can't be sure, but maybe it has something to do with bootstrapping?  I was seeing some bootstrapping errors (again only on VS not MONO - Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperLocator.Bootstrapper related) until I added Nancy.Owin reference to EXE, even though Nancy.Owin reference was present in a dependent DLL.

Please help!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the EXE was using .NET 4.5.1 but the DLLs were .NET 4.5

I saw no specific 4.5.1 DLL's actually being referenced, but there must be one lurking about in there somewhere because changing EXE to .NET 4.5 and cleaning up packages.config fixed this issue.